# Getting error message "The minimal damping factor of 1/10000 has been reached"

Tags: differential-equations, finite-element-method

As a very beginner into Mathematica, I encounter error message as shown below when I am solving the system of three second order ODEs numerically using `ParametricNDSolveValue`:

> FindRoot::dfmin: The minimal damping factor of 1/10000 has been
> reached.

> ParametricNDSolveValue::fempsf: PDESolve could not find a
> solution.

Below is the essential part of my codes, starting with list of constants,

```
(*List of constants*)
w = 1; 
p = 1; 
q = 0.05; 
u = 1; 
Rba = 0; 
Rca = 1; 
Kb = 1.38*10^-23; 
T = 25 + 273; 
miumaxC = 0;
alphaA = 20;
alphaB = 20;
alphaC = 1;
betaA = 1;
betaB = 1;
betaC = 1;
kgA = 1;
kgB = 1;
kgC = 1;
```

Intermediate functions,

```
(*intermediate functions*)
cp1[x_] = miumaxA/2*(1 - Tanh[alphaA (x - betaA)])*Kb*T; 
cp2[x_] = miumaxB/2*(1 - Tanh[alphaB (x - betaB)])*Kb*T; 
cp3[x_] = miumaxC/2*(1 - Tanh[alphaC (x - betaC)])*Kb*T; 
diffintermediate1[x_] = a[x]*x^2*cp1'[x];
diffintermediate2[x_] = b[x]*x^2*cp2'[x];
diffintermediate3[x_] = (phi[x] - 1)*x^2*cp3'[x];
```

Defining ODEs and boundary conditions before solving,

```
(*Dimensionless species balance equations with neumann BCs for \
species A,B,and C*)
ODE1 = a''[x] + 2/x*a'[x] + 1/(Kb*T)/x^2*diffintermediate1'[x] - 
   TM^2*phi[x]*a[x] == 
  NeumannValue[0, x == 0] + 
   NeumannValue[kgA*(a[x] - 1), x == 1]; ODE2  = 
 b''[x] + 2/x*b'[x] + 1/(Kb*T)/x^2*diffintermediate2'[x] + 
   TM^2*phi[x]/p*(a[x] - w*b[x]) == 
  NeumannValue[0, x == 0] + NeumannValue[kgB/p* (b[x]), x == 1];
ODE3  = q*(phi''[x] + 2/x*phi'[x] + 
       1/(Kb*T)/x^2*diffintermediate3'[x]) - TM^2*u*w*phi[x]*b[x] == 
   NeumannValue[0, x == 0] + NeumannValue[kgC/q* (phi[x] - 1), x == 1];

(*Grouping the ODEs for input in NDSolveValue function*)
ODEs = {ODE1, ODE2 , ODE3}; 

(*Solving the system of ODES*)
solutions = 
  ParametricNDSolveValue[{ODEs}, {a, b, phi}, {x, 0, 1}, {TM, 
    miumaxA, miumaxB}];
```

I would get the abovementioned error message when I try to calculate and plot the solutions at `TMplot = 10` to investigate the effect of different `miumax`. Below is the code for plotting the solutions:

```
MiumaxList = {-4,-2,0,2,4};
(*Solution profile plotting at different miumaxA*)
TMplot  =10;

(*Creating legend colours*)
legendColours = {};
legendEntries = {};
For[i=1,i<=Length[MiumaxList],i++,
legendColours = Insert[legendColours,RGBColor[0.2*i,0.35,0.7],i];
]

(*Creating list of solutions for varying Miumax*)
solutionListA = {};
solutionListB = {};
solutionListPhi = {};
For[i=1,i<=Length[MiumaxList],i++,
solutionListA= Insert[solutionListA,solutions[TMplot,MiumaxList[[i]],MiumaxList[[i]]][[1]][x] ,i];
solutionListB = Insert[solutionListB,solutions[TMplot,MiumaxList[[i]],MiumaxList[[i]]][[2]][x] ,i];
solutionListPhi = Insert[solutionListPhi,solutions[TMplot,MiumaxList[[i]],MiumaxList[[i]]][[3]][x] ,i];
];

(*Plotting of solutions a, b, and phi for varying Miumax*)
Plot[solutionListA,{x,0,1},PlotRange->{Automatic,Full},PlotLabel->"a (x) at different miumax pair, TM = "[TMplot],AxesLabel->{"x","a(x)"},PlotStyle->legendColours,PlotLegends->LineLegend[legendColours,MiumaxList]]
Plot[solutionListB,{x,0,1},PlotRange->{Automatic,Full},PlotLabel->"b (x) at different miumax pair, TM = "[TMplot],AxesLabel->{"x","a(x)"},PlotStyle->legendColours,PlotLegends->LineLegend[legendColours,MiumaxList]]
Plot[solutionListPhi,{x,0,1},PlotRange->{Automatic,Full},PlotLabel->"a (x) at different miumax pair, TM = "[TMplot],AxesLabel->{"x","a(x)"},PlotStyle->legendColours,PlotLegends->LineLegend[legendColours,MiumaxList]]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two things you can try. In version 13.1 parametric functions when used with the finite element method can take a new initial seeding. This is relevant in your case as the nonliterary is very strong as numbers increase and a good initial seed might help to push the solutions further out.

Let's have a look:

```
(*Solving the system of ODES*)
solutions = 
  ParametricNDSolveValue[{ODEs}, {a, b, phi}, {x, 0, 1}, {TM, miumaxA,
     miumaxB}];
```

We can compute a solution for this set of parameters:

```
oldSolution = solutions[3, -4, -4]
(* InterpolatingFunction[.... *)
```

But when we increase the 3 to a 4 we get a convergence error:

```
solutions[4, -4, -4]
```

[image]

What you can do now is to use the `oldSolution` as an initial seed for the next solution like so:

```
solutions[4, -4, -4, 
 "InitialSeeding" -> 
  Thread[Through[{a, b, phi}[x]] == Through[oldSolution[x]]]]
```

I can not say how far you can push these out but give it a shot. If this does not work, not all hope is lost. There is a second way to do this. In that case you convert your stationary ODEs to time dependent ODEs and time integrate them for a pseudo time from 0 to 1 and use for example the first parameter like

```
NDSolve[ tsolutions[t*10, -4, -4],..., {t,0,1},...]
```

This has the advantage that the adaptive time stepping algorithm of NDSolve will take care of the step size selection; on the downside you need to set up a time dependent problem and initial conditions.

Both approaches are shown in the monograph on [Hyperelasticity](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/PDEModels/tutorial/StructuralMechanics/Hyperelasticity.html).

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you so much for the advice. I just tried the first method, which is to alter the initial seeding by calling it using `solutions[4, -4, -4, 
 "InitialSeeding" -> 
Thread[Through[{a, b, phi}[x]] == Through[oldSolution[x]]]]`. 
However, I would get error:
"ParametricNDSolveValue::fpct: Too many parameters in {TM,miumaxA,miumaxB} to be filled from ... ..."
It seems like I have to change the initial seedings in `ParametricNDSolveValue[... ...]`. Is there any workaround that changes the initial seeding after declaring `ParametricNDSolveValue`?

Comment: @joe, what is you $Version?

Comment: I am currently using ver 13.0.1.0

Comment: @joe, as mentioned in the beginning of the post, the above works in version 13.1. In version 13.0 you'd have to try the second method that I outlined. Make this a time dependent problem and add a factor of `t` in front of the parameters.