# How to extract individual solution from a list of interpolating functions?

Tags: differential-equations

I am solving a system consisted of [3 ODEs](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/270389/getting-error-message-the-minimal-damping-factor-of-1-10000-has-been-reached/270460#270460) using `ParametricNDSolveValue`. Everytime when I want to obtain each solution at certain parameters, I would use:

```
solutions = ParametricNDSolveValue[{ODEs}, {a, b, phi}, {x, 0, 1}, {TM, miumaxA, miumaxB}];
asol[x_]=solutions[para1val,para2val,para3val][[1]][x];
bsol[x_]=solutions[para1val,para2val,para3val][[2]][x];
phisol[x_]=solutions[para1val,para2val,para3val][[3]][x];
```

However, this might waste computational resource, as the solution is computed 3 times, in each line. Then, I try :

```
{asol,bsol,phisol}=solutions[para1val,para2val,para3val][x];
```

However, this does not work. `solutions[para1val,para2val,para3val][x]` would give a list of three interpolating functions. Is there any way to extract interpolating function of each solution once `solutions[para1val,para2val,para3val][x]` is evaluated?

Comment: It would be better to provide code that is self-contained. As it stands, everyone has to invent their own ode to run your code. In any event, try dropping `[x]` and write `{asol,bsol,phisol} = solutions[para1val,para2val,para3val]` instead, does that do it? For example, try evaluating `asol[0.5]` afterwards.

Comment: Try to write `asol[x_]:=solutions...` instead of `asol[x_]=solutions...`. You may also define `sol[x_, n_Integer]:=solutions[para1val,para2val,para3val][[n]][x]`, which yields you the solution definition for all values `n=1,2,3`. In principle, this makes what you want: the function definition persisting through the whole Mma session.

Comment: @user293787 The complete code is available in the [link](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/270389/getting-error-message-the-minimal-damping-factor-of-1-10000-has-been-reached?noredirect=1&lq=1) provided in the question.

Comment: @user293787 By dropping `[x]` , I am able to get `asol[x]`, `bsol[x]`, and `phisol[x]` as separated interpolating function. Your help is very much appreciated.

@AlexeiBoulbitch By changing to `:=`, I would get error message "dSetDelayed::shape".

Comment: `ParametricNDSolveValue` caches results by default, so the ODEs won't be repeatedly solved and re-solved. It was designed with your sort of use-case in mind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turning the comment to an answer:

`ParametricNDSolveValue` caches results by default, so the ODEs won't be repeatedly solved and re-solved. It was designed with your sort of use-case in mind.